# Error in c socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, udpclient

```
int acceptSocket;
struct sockaddr_in addr, client, dest;
char buf[256];
long rc, sentbytes;
int port = 18017;

int CreateSocket()
{



    if(rc!=0)

       {

         printf("socket failure code: %ld\n",rc);

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("socket started!\n");

       }

       // Socket creation for UDP

       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)

       {

         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("Socket started!\n");

       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

     addr.sin_port=htons(port);

     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc==-1)

     {

       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

       return 1;

     }

     else

     {

       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);

     }




       while(rc!=-1)
       {
         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, sizeof(client));
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
           printf("failure: recv, failure code\n");
           break;
         }
         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
            makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
            makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms

     //    buf[rc]='\0';
     //    printf("Client sendet: %s\n",buf);
     //    sprintf(buf2,"Du mich auch %s",buf);
     //    rc=sendto(connectedSocket,buf2,strlen(buf2),0);

       }


       close(acceptSocket);



       return 0;

     }
```

I created a socket for udp layer and it is waiting for connection from the client and later sending the data to the client. My program is getting crashed in listen mode. i.e: after bind :I am getting error as

```
 printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");
```

Could anyone tell me why?
@JoachimPileborg: it is not working!! again the same problem. I am not able to comment there.

Comment: When you get an error, you can actually see *what* the error is by printing the value of [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html). You can get a printable string from the error code by calling [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strerror.html). Please edit your question to include the error code (and string).

Comment: UDP does not do connections.

Comment: Something is wrong with the Enter key on your keyboard.

Comment: is `acceptSocket` defined global?

Comment: Your code does not show `rc`'s declaration, nor where it is written before the first time it's read. Is that a global variable? And if yes, why?

Comment: now i edited my code.

Comment: it is a global variable!! whats wrong in that ??

Comment: @user3252048 As UDP isn't connection oriented, you don't actually have clients as such. You have to wait until a client communicates with the server, and then keep track of the clients.

Comment: @user3252048 please check if port already in use or not give the out put of `netstat -a | grep "18017"`

Comment: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-server.c

Comment: I solved it. problem was the port number.

Comment: @user3252048 Can you be more specific? Was it an illegal port number? Was it in use? What *was* the problem, and how did you solve it?

Comment: port number was already in use.

Comment: If i recieve a request from the client then the recieve is failure. Why so ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to find actual error.you can do as follows

As bind man page

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

The standard procedure in every POSIX call, there is an integer named errno that contains the value of the actual error. You can either check its value manually, or use primitives as [perror](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/perrorman.html) or strerror

```
if (rc  == -1) 
{
    perror("socket error");
}
```

must have `#include<errno.h>`

Now bind fails many reason one of it like

Probably some other application is listening on that port. You can find this by running

```
netstat -a | grep "18017"
```

So if you found port in use then switch to another port number or simply kill that process which uses that port.

Also please update you `while...loop` in proper format like no need to compare `rc` to both `-1` and `0` please do as follows

```
   while(1)
   {
        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((rc = recvfrom(acceptSocket, buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client)) == -1)   // read datagram from server socket
        {
            break;
        }
       //rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: i had a problem with port number.

Comment: If i recieve a request from the client then the recieve is failure. Why so ??

Comment: @user3252048 please look updated post.

Comment: i modified as you said but then alsi it is not recieving any data from client. why so ??

Comment: @user3252048 is client send any data?

Comment: In my code : rc = recvfrom(); so i was calling this api with XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );   //if I do as your then what should I use for the first parameter ??

Comment: @user3252048 please see my edited answer for `while..loop`